# Need a WYSIWYG editor with image upload option

Tags: php, ckeditor, tinymce, wysiwyg, image-uploading

I need a WYSIWYG php editor(e.g tinyMCE or CKeditor) with image upload option.I am able to configure the editor but unable to upload images or any other files.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific and therefor already received some close votes.

You might want to have a look at the tinymce 4 full example with all available functionality (to be found [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/)). Have a look at the configuration there and see what is missing (The tabs 'HTML' and 'JS').

Comment: I apologize if i was not clear. I want to upload pictures from my computer (not using a URL).

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but [Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) is really good and it has a detailed example for image upload with PHP: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/server-integrations/php-image-upload.

Also, by default it uploads file to their own server, which is great if you want something for demo purposes quickly.